# Can I add 3.5% Surcharge Fee for Credit Card Payment ?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add **3.5% Surcharge Fee** to the **Total Shopping Cart Quote** for using Credit Card option.  Is this possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does solve your problem ??

Comment: try this https://magecomp.com/magento-payment-surcharge.html

Comment: For Magento 2, I have created a module. Look at this: https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-paymentfee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is quite possible. If you would like to show it as a separate total you could create a new total collector for surcharge fee : [see here:](http://www.classyllama.com/blog/unravelling-magentos-collecttotals-example)

If you would just like to add the 3.5% surcharge without showing it as a separate component you could hook into the event: `sales_quote_save_before and sales_quote_address_save_before` and write code to add 4.5% surcharge to quote and address grand total

`if $quoteObject->getPayment()->getMethod() == 'cc'`

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps I would have followed to implement the above request -:

Step 1 -

Create two fields (surcharge and base surcharge) against quote address and order

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("ALTER TABLE  `".$this->getTable('sales/quote_address')."` ADD `surcharge` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE  `".$this->getTable('sales/quote_address')."` ADD `base_surcharge` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL");

$installer->run("ALTER TABLE  `".$this->getTable('sales/order')."` ADD `surcharge` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL");
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE  `".$this->getTable('sales/order')."` ADD `base_surcharge` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL");


$installer->endSetup();
```

Step 2 - Add the following to config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <CompanyName_Surcharge>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </CompanyName_Surcharge>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <blocks>
          <surcharge>
             <class>CompanyName_Surcharge_Block</class>
          </surcharge>
          <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <order_totals>CompanyName_Surcharge_Block_Sales_Order_Total</order_totals>
            </rewrite>
          </sales>
       </blocks>
       <helpers>
         <surcharge>
            <class>Company_Surcharge_Helper</class>
         </surcharge>
       </helpers> 
       <models>
          <surcharge>
             <class>CompanyName_Surcharge_Model</class>
         </surcharge>
       </models>
       <sales>
          <quote>
            <totals>
                <surcharge>
                    <class>CompanyName_Surcharge_Model_Total_Quote</class>
                    <after>subtotal</after>
                    <before>tax</before>
                </surcharge>
            </totals>
         </quote>
      </sales>
      <fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote_address>
            <surcharge>
                <to_order>*</to_order>
            </surcharge>
            <base_surcharge>
                <to_order>*</to_order>
            </base_surcharge>
        </sales_convert_quote_address>
      </fieldsets>
   </global>
</config>
```

Step 3 - Create Model app\code\community\CompanyName\Surcharge\Model\Total\Quote.php

```
<?php

class CompanyName_Surcharge_Model_Total_Quote extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract {

    protected $_code = 'surcharge';

    /**
     * Initialize surcharge totals collector
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setCode($this->_code);
    }

    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) 
    {
        parent::collect($address);

        $this->_setAmount(0);
        $this->_setBaseAmount(0);

        $items = $this->_getAddressItems($address);
        if (!count($items)) {
            return $this;
        }

        $grandTotal= Mage::getModel('sales/quote_address')->load($address->getId())->getData('grand_total');            
        $baseSurcharge = 0;
        $surcharge = 0;

        $baseSurcharge += (($grandTotal) * (3.5 / 100));
        $surcharge += Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice($baseSurcharge);

        $address->setSurcharge($surcharge);
        $address->setBaseSurcharge($baseSurcharge);

        $this->_addAmount($address->getSurcharge());
        $this->_addBaseAmount($address->getBaseSurcharge());

        return $this;
    }

    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {
        $amount = $address->getSurcharge();
        if ($amount > 0) {
            $address->addTotal(array(
                'code' => $this->getCode(),
                'title' => 'Surcharge',
                'value' => $amount
            ));
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Step 4 - Create Block app\code\community\CompanyName\Surcharge\Block\Sales\Order\Total.php

```
<?php

class CompanyName_Surcharge_Block_Sales_Order_Total extends Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Totals {

    protected function _initTotals() {
        parent::_initTotals();
        $surcharge = $this->getSource()->getSurcharge();
        $baseSurcharge = $this->getSource()->getBaseSurcharge();

        if ($surcharge != 0) {
            $this->addTotal(new Varien_Object(array(
                'code' => 'surcharge',
                'value' => $surcharge,
                'base_value' => $baseSurcharge,
                'label' => Mage::helper('surcharge')->getLabel(),
                    )), 'surcharge');
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Hope the above helps but if you are not a developer then you can use the following module which can be used to address the above issue along with more flexibility -:

http://www.scommerce-mage.co.uk/magento-surcharge-or-additional-fee.html

Cheers
S

Comment: using above method invoice is not created for surcharge, Invoice is being created only for other than sur charge amount

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer, this new order total should also show up in transactional emails and other places.

This post explains this in details:
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/

There's also a really simple extension which lets you do this:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/26312/super-simple-surcharge/

You can add a single surcharge for any payment method, shipping method or customer group. You can either calculate your surcharge based on a percentage value or use a flat value.